# (Android) Duda 'Canvas.drawText'

Tags: java, android

Buenas,
quisiera mostrar un texto,(sobre todo letras),en mi canvas.
La idea es que cada vez que llame al oncliklistener del view,se muestren una letras en pantalla.

He visto que podría funcionar con 'Canvas.drawText'
¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Deberías añadir código para que resulte más fácil ayudarte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es eso lo que buscas? Con el metodo `fillText()`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"
style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the canvas element.
</canvas>

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "30px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Texto",10,50);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Con el metodo `drawText()` que mencionabas:

```
Paint paint = new Paint(); 
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
paint.setStyle(Style.FILL); 
canvas.drawPaint(paint); 

paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
paint.setTextSize(20); 
canvas.drawText("Texto", 10, 25, paint);
```